# Shorten WordPress dates and times

Tags: php, wordpress

I use [human_time_diff](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff) Wordpress function on a small area in a thumbnail to show from how much time is it posted, and it appears like: `2 hours` , `24 mins` ...., and I was wondering if I can make it shorter, like `2h`, `24m`, I'm sure it could be changed somewhere, can I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has a filter available to do this:

```
add_filter( 'human_time_diff', function($since, $diff, $from, $to) {

  $replace = array(
    'min'  => 'm',
    'mins' => 'm',
    'hour'  => 'h',
    'hours' => 'h',
    'day'   => 'd',
    'days'  => 'd',
  );

  return strtr($since, $replace);

}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: man, you made my day! thank you. Please notice the typo, change the min and mins symbol to `m` instead of `h`.

Comment: Changed it. Cheers!